# Make a program just run without having to use terminal to make it run

Tags: c, terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make a C launcher on my Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478306/make-a-c-launcher-on-my-mac)

I've made a program with c, but I have to type in ~/a.out everytime I want it to run. Is there a way I can make it run just by double clicking it? Or any other way

Comment: What happens if you double-click it ?

Comment: What operating system are you using? In what environment (file browser?) do you want to double-click your program?

Comment: Assuming that you can run it like that from the command line, any suitably smart window manager will run it for you if you just double click it.  However if it doesn't do anything other than read/write from stdin/stdout, you won't really be able to see it running unless the window manager is smart enough to also open it in a terminal.

Comment: I'm using a MacBook pro. When I double click it, it opens some text editor with the code inside. It doesn't just run it

Comment: You're double clicking a.out and not the source file, right?

Comment: I've been double clicking the source file. How do I click a.out?

Comment: Double clicking the source file will just open it in an editor as you said.  As @BenBurns said, try double clicking on a.out or whatever the compiled program is called.  Only the compiled version of your program is executable.

Comment: 'it opens some text editor with the code inside' are you double-clicked the source code?

Answer (score 1):

A command-line program needs a console in order to have somewhere to send stdout/stdin.  Launching your program by itself causes it to run, but stdout isn't connected to anything that can display to the screen.  You have to run your program inside a terminal in order for it to behave as you expect.

Depending on your OS, you have some options.  If you are running Linux and have a Gnome-based desktop environment, you can create a launcher for your app.  When creating the launcher, you will have an option to "run program in terminal".  If you select that option, then double-clicking on the launcher will launch a terminal and run your program inside of it.

There are similar methods available for other systems.  What OS/desktop environment are you running?

*Update:* I'm not too familiar with OSX, but given that it has a bash shell you should be able to use a bash script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/X11/bin/xterm -e /path/to/my_app
```

You'll want to adjust the paths to `bash` and `xterm` based on where they're actually located on your system (running `which bash` in the terminal should show you).

Comment: I am using OSX. How do I make a launcher?

Comment: @TannerEllis - [XCode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/).

Comment: @TannerEllis- See my update.  I have limited experience with OSX, but you should be able to launch it via a simple shell script. You'd be double-clicking on the script and not directly on the program, but it's the same idea.

Comment: @TannerEllis- When it comes to doing Mac-specific things like this, you may get a better answer asking on http://apple.stackexchange.com/