# Make a C launcher on my Mac

Tags: c, macos, terminal

I want to make a launcher for a c program I made and I want it to run in terminal. How would I do this? I don't even have the slightest idea

Comment: Please give us as many details as possible.  Is this program you wrote a console program/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a text file, save it to the Desktop as e.g. `my_C_program.command` (note the `.command` suffix), then in the text file you can put whatever terminal commands you like, e.g.

```
# run my_C_program
my_C_program arg1 arg2
```

Note: after saving the `.command` file you need to make sure it is executable:

```
$ chmod +x ~/Desktop/my_C_program.command
```

This will give you a double-clickable icon on the desktop called `my_C_program` that runs `my_C_program` via the command line. (This assumes `my_C_program` is somewhere in your `PATH`).

Comment: I made the script and when I double clicked it, it said I didn't have the access privelages

Comment: You need to make sure that whatever you put in the `.command` script will actually run if you paste it into a Terminal window.

Comment: Oops - I missed out an important final step - see edited answer above.

Comment: Okay, I will try this in about 20 minutes and I'll tell you if it works or not. Thanks ahead of time though!

Comment: I just tested the above on OS X 10.7.4 and it seems to work as expected.

Comment: Once you've compiled your program put the executable somewhere in your `PATH`, e.g. `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

- Double-click your programm
- You will asked for a programm to open your programm (sounds strage, I know)
- Search for "Terminal" & Choose it

That's it! Now your programm should open when you double-click it.